# How do you run stored procedure in a batch

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase

I am using Aqua Data Studio and sybase. 
Say I have 20 different stored procedures created in database 1, now I need to migrate all the stored procedures to database 2. Can I do this in batch mode?

Currently, I have to copy the content of each store procedure into query analyser in Aqua Studio and hit "run" button, and I have to do it 20 times.

Surely there must be an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the product "Aqua Data Studio" but what i would do is the following:

use sp_helptext  to get the sql for all your procs and then copy them in a SQL file which you can run against database 2.

not sure if that is actually what your third party product is doing. anyway, as far as i know there is no other way as long as you don't have saved the original sql files for the creation in database 1 ;-)

hope that helps